# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found from 4.2 to 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to update my Laravel from 4.2 to 5.7 and I started by creating a new project and moving my files. After moving my controllers I now have an error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found.

Here is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{ 

    protected $messageBag = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // CSRF Protection
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));

        //
        $this->messageBag = new Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
    }

    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout)) {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

I also tried composer dump-autoload and I have the following in my composer file

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
},
```

Comment: Is there a Controller at `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php`?

Comment: no but isn't the extends Controller basically extending from the main controller of laravel framework?

Comment: Nope. You'd need `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;` for that, not `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`.

Comment: You can create `Controller.php` in your `app/Http/Controllers` folder, with [following content](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php). If you created a new project, it should have been there. How did you create new project?